# "You need 150 reputation to vote" error message is too low

Tags: bug, design, moderator-election, error-message

Knowing that users with less than 150 reputation can't vote in elections, I tried to vote in the election with a low-reputation sock puppet just to see what happens. As expected, I got an error message, but it's positioned sub-optimally:

[image: "You need at least 150 reputation to vote"]

I think the error message should be displayed underneath the voting buttons, rather than at the very bottom of the nomination. New users who don't know that voting in the election requires a minimum reputation score might not see it all the way down there if they haven't scrolled the page, and this may make them think that the button isn't working.

This might not be a very important issue, but I still think it would improve the usability to move the error message up.

Comment: Better yet: if you don't have the 150 rep, the voting buttons shouldn't even be there.

Comment: @JoeC not the bug OP meant, but the bug that was needed.

Comment: Instead, would it be better if we allowed people with less than 150 rep to vote, but have their vote carry a lesser weight?

Comment: @George There is a question on Meta Stack Exchange asking that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135778/349538

Comment: @DonaldDuck : Thank you for the reference. My question was whether we could attach a weighted score based on badges, and other activity counters. Nevertheless, I figured out the answer myself. Cheers!

Comment: Displaying voting buttons to users with <150 reputation is not a bug. It is [effective UI design](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/07/01/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/). An error message that is difficult to read is the bug, as accurately reported here.

Comment: @CodyGray : Would it be right to guess if that's Stack Overflow's way of telling users to contribute more to the site in order to gain this privilege?

Comment: Sure, I guess so @George. That's one way to look at it. The way I see it, I imagine myself as a user with 125 reputation, I see an election going on, and I decide to try and vote in it. If I had read all the text at the top, I would have seen that 150 reputation was a requirement for voting, but we all know no one reads all that text, so I just look for the option to vote. I don't find it, get frustrated, and either blame myself or decide that the site is buggy. That's a bad user experience. Better to have the expected vote buttons, and when I click on them, *explain why* the operation failed.

Comment: After reading the text on the right side panel (where this info is), II was surprised seeing the voting buttons anyway, because I have <150 rep. I agree that the placement of the blue message, as well as the mention of the reputation pre-requisite, could be improved, maybe to be a part of the main text rather than exist on the side panel. PS: When I see buttons, I click, and then wait for response :D

Comment: Exactly.  I would replace the buttons with a text block saying "You need at least 150 reputation to vote in this election."

Comment: @George The 150 rep requirement is only there to prevent abuse, it's not so that only higher repped people can vote. So giving a weight to votes is not really needed. In fact, I'd go as far as saying that it's unfair and undemocratic to give some people more say than others.